# Clarification needed regarding average power through a load

Tags: power, resistors, phasor

The question for the following circuit was to find the average power through the load \$ Z_{L} \$.

The first and second image shows that \$ I_{2} \$ and \$ V_{2} \$ were found. I assumed that the average power through the load could be then found by the formula:

$$
I_{2(rms)}*V_{2(rms)} * cos(18.43 + 45)
$$

[image: Exam question (1)]

[image: Exam question (2)]

However, this appears to yield a different answer to that obtained in the image, where the average power is found directly via the resistor and \$ P = 62.51W \$ is obtained:

[image: Exam question (3)]

Could someone please explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly I found out that my error was a small and stupid calculation mistake that I was consistently making while inputting my values into a calculator. Both methods do yield the same answer.